# Ruby Class Instance Variable not cleared between method call : Integer class

Tags: ruby, class, instance-variables

I have the following code for an assignment.  After much debugging I found what was happening

```
class Integer
    def initialize()
      @ans = ""
    end

    def ans
      @ans = ""
    end

    def ans=(value)
      @ans = value
    end

    def to_base(base)
      # convert given number into the base
      # figure out how to make it the most efficient
      num = self
      r = 0
      loop do
        r = num % base              # modulus
        @ans = r.to_s + @ans.to_s   # add to answer
        num /= base                 # division 
        break unless num != 0
      end
      english = @ans                # return value
    end

    def to_oct
      self.to_base(8)
    end
end

puts 8.to_oct
puts 8.to_base(2)
```

Output:

```
10
100010
```

The output for the binary version should be `1000` not `100010`
What it did was append the first instance of the class `8.to_oct` onto the second call `8.to_base(2)`

Is there a way to have this cleared as I want to use the same number (8) in this example and convert it to various base numbers.  what am I doing wrong in my class?

Thanks!

Comment: A few good rules to follow: 1) never refer to instance variables in your code, other than in initializers. Use accessors or other references instead. In this class, I can't really tell what benefit the variable gives you anyway. 2) Do not patch `Integer` or other Ruby core classes. They're more often than not implemented in C and will not always behave consistently if you start redefining how they work. Make a new class to wrap around `Integer` instead.

Comment: @ZachKemp what do you mean by other accessors / references?  Can you point me to a good example of doing this?

Comment: @ZachKemp I don’t agree with your first point, but the second point is important—especially for the `initialize` method.

Comment: @camdixon, it means that you should use methods to access your variables, instead of referring to them directly. This makes every action the result of a message send, which I would say is the primary characteristic of object oriented design.

Comment: Also, `Integer` in Ruby core isn’t actually a class, it’s a method.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, going to have to disagree there. `Integer` is a class, `Integer()` is a Kernel type coercion method